# Make element 100% of body when inside fixed width - IE6 BUG

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

Pretty sure this is an IE6 bug as it works in all other browsers.

[jsFiddle of this html code](http://jsfiddle.net/WjD3x/) :

```
        <div style="background:blue; width:600px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
            BLUE
            <div style="background:red; position:absolute; width:100%; left:0;">
                red
            </div>
        </div>
```

So the "RED" div should be 100% width of its container (in this case the body). In IE6 it is always the 600px. Is there a fix for it that doesn't involve ignoring ie6? ( I wish I could, believe me!)

Comment: Without CSS and complete HTML i am unable to help you. And has a member for 1 year - 4 months you must understand what i mean.

Comment: You could try setting `position: relative` to the body.

Comment: Only about 1% of visitors use the IE6 browser nowadays. I would not care about it.

Comment: It's container is the parent div not body.

Comment: I've marked the "1%" comment as useful as usually in this situation that is the way I'd think. However for complicated reasons I need to do something with IE6. One of those annoying situations where I'll need to change my CSS and HTML structure just to suit this frickin browser! - thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.
An absolute position element is positioned **relative** to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is `<html>`

So, for your inner div to be positionned 'absolute' relatively to it's parent, you would have to make it's parent positionned **relative**

[jsFiddle showing your code with parent div relative](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxr2a/1/)

```
<div style="background:blue; width:600px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;position:relative">BLUE
    <div style="background:red; position:absolute; width:100%; left:0;">red</div>
</div>
```

For the rest of your situation (ie6 bug?), i need more code.

Comment: Thanks for setting up the fiddle. - I'll do that next time.

I understand how the position relative works. In my case it would take it from the body... which it does for all browsers except IE 6. It's as though it always gets the width from its container. Interestingly you can position it to the body with "left:0" but the width is always on the container.